# My Angular 11 cli app not working with jest. Error I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'paths' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

My Angular 11 cli app not working with jest.

When I do npm run test e.g. jest --updateSnapshot I get the error in my terminal below:

**Error** I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'paths' of undefined

**Tsconfig:**

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "esModuleInterop": false,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "rootDir": ".",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
      "types": [
        "socket.io-client"
      ],
      "lib": [
          "dom",
          "es2018"
      ],
      "paths": {
      },
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
      "target": "es5",
      "typeRoots": [
          "node_modules/@types"
      ]
  }
}
```

**Package:**

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --output-hashing=all",
    "test": "jest --updateSnapshot",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch --updateSnapshot",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "deploy": "npm run build && firebase deploy",
    "precommit": "run-s prettier:fix lint",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier --config ./.prettierrc --write \"src/{app,environments,assets}/**/*{.ts,.js,.json,.css,.scss}\"",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --config ./.prettierrc --list-different \"src/{app,environments,assets}/**/*{.ts,.js,.json,.css,.scss}\""
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run precommit"
    }
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/common": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.9",
    "@angular/fire": "6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.9",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.1100.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.0.9",
    "@google-cloud/speech": "^4.1.4",
    "@hackages/ngxerrors": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.7.0",
    "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.7.0",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.0",
    "@sentry/browser": "^5.27.4",
    "@types/aos": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.34",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "basscss-sass": "^4.0.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.0",
    "firebase": "^7.19.1",
    "gridlex": "^2.7.1",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-open-cv": "^0.3.1",
    "ng2-truncate": "^1.3.17",
    "ngx-prevent-double-submission": "^0.1.0",
    "ngx-socket-io": "^3.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "puppeteer": "^5.5.0",
    "recordrtc": "^5.6.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "socket.io": "^3.0.3",
    "socket.io-client": "^3.0.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.9",
    "@testing-library/angular": "^10.1.4",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cypress": "^5.6.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^8.3.2",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  }
}
```

**jest.config.js:**

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig');

module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src/'],
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec).+(ts)'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test.ts'],
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage/cllear',
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths || {}, {
    prefix: '<rootDir>/',
  }),
};
```

**test.js**

```
import 'jest-preset-angular';

Object.defineProperty(window, 'CSS', { value: null });
Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      display: 'none',
      appearance: ['-webkit-appearance'],
    };
  },
});

Object.defineProperty(document, 'doctype', {
  value: '<!DOCTYPE html>',
});
Object.defineProperty(document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need change the value of `compilerOptions` variable, set it to:

```
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig.spec.json');
```

By the way it's helped to me.